# Applying different class to different dated results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
 ______________________
| Name |    Date       |
 ----------------------
| Bob  |  2016-09-16   |
| Ben  |  2016-10-03   |
| Sam  |  2016-10-03   |
```

Using the following:

```
SELECT 
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  = 3 then '3 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  > 6 then  '7 or more days'
end as days,
sum( case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  <= 3 then 1 
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then 1
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  > 6 then 1
else 0 
end  ) as tot 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  <= 3 then '3 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(),`the_date`) > 6 then  '7 or more days'
end ;
```

and then using

```
echo '<p>'.$row['tot'].'</p>';
```

I'm getting the following results sorting my rows in to whether rows are less than 3 days old, 4 to 6 days old, or over 7 days old.

```
1
2
```

Ideally I'd like to apply a class to the p tags such as class="urgent" for the ones that are older than 7 days, orange for 4 to 6 days and then green for up to 3 days. I'd then like to wrap the number with unique text such as "You urgently need to reply to **result** application"

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with here?  Looks like you've gotten the hard parts figured out already

Comment: All I'm getting as a result is `1 2` I'd like to wrap these results uniquely,

Comment: Show the PHP that executes the query

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you could just use a `count` to get `tot` rather than that complex expression, since every case returns `1` and you're already grouping by that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd test the data result for the value you're looking for, and conditionally assign a class name depending on the value.

```
if ($row['days'] == '7 or more days') {
    $css_class = 'urgent';
} else {
    $css_class = 'normal';
}

printf("<p class='%s'>%s</p>", $css_class, $row['tot']);
```

I would *not* recommend hardcoding your css class name in your query. Don't mix your database queries with your presentation layer, that will just create confusion and inappropriate coupling in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column )my_class) in your query and add the result in your p tag

```
SELECT 
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  = 3 then '3 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  > 6 then  '7 or more days'
end as days,
sum( case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  <= 3 then 1 
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then 1
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  > 6 then 1
else 0 
end  ) as tot ,
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  = 3 then 'green'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then 'orange'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  > 6 then  'red'
end as my_class 


FROM my_table 
GROUP BY
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  <= 3 then '3 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `the_date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(),`the_date`) > 6 then  '7 or more days'
end ;  


echo '<p  class="'. $row['my_class'] . '" >'.$row['tot'].'</p>'; your query with the proper class a
```